# Pandas Period to to_timestamp giving me TypeError

Tags: pandas, datetime, period

I have a Pandas Dataframe of the format as shown below:

```
   Month     Count  
   2021-02    100
   2021-03    200
```

Where the "Month" column is obtained from a timestamp using *dt.to_period('M')*.

Now I have to convert this "Month" column to a fiscal quarter and I have used some approaches to convert the Period to a "datetime" object using "to_timestamp", but I get the error

> TypeError: unsupported Type Int64Index

Is there another way to approach this problem?

Comment: Can you add your code to question?

Answer (score 8):

If working with a column, it is necessary to add `.dt`. If omitting it, Pandas tries to convert `DatetimeIndex` and if it does not exist, it raises an error, because it called [`DataFrame.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_timestamp.html) instead of `Series.dt.to_timestamp`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Month'].to_timestamp()
```

> TypeError: unsupported Type RangeIndex

```
df['Date'] = df['Month'].dt.to_timestamp()
print (df)
     Month  Count       Date
0  2021-02    100 2021-02-01
1  2021-03    200 2021-03-01
```

The solution for a fiscal quarter is to use [`Series.dt.qyear`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.qyear.html). Better documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.qyear.html):

```
df['fquarter'] = df['Month'].dt.qyear
print (df)
     Month  Count  fquarter
0  2021-02    100      2021
1  2021-03    200      2021
```